# Can't ping computers on local network over WiFi on Windows, but can with Mac

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, router

**Update**: It looks like there is something materially wrong with both routers in my house; the issues above seem to resolve if I do a full power-down (i.e. unplug): Pause 1 minute, and then re-power everything, starting with the basement router, then the second floor router, and then re-enabling WiFi on all devices.  Both routers are older models; as a next step I may try installing DD-WRT on the basement router and seeing if that fixes anything.

---

I've got two routers connected via ethernet on two different floors of my house, both with the same SSID, and identical security settings.

When connecting via ethernet to either router, all computers can see each other. E.g. basement-1 can ping secondfloor-1, and vice-versa.

When connecting via WiFi, my Windows 10 machine, which is connected to the router on the second floor, cannot see any machines in the basement.  This problem does not exist for other devices (e.g. macOS, iPad, or Android tablets).

Some additonal informaiton based on questions so far:

- To test, I renamed the router on the second floor to a new SSID.  This ensured I was not actually connected to the basement router
- Network setup is as follows:

  - Basement Router: 192.168.13.2 (stock D-Link)
  - Second Floor Router: 192.168.13.8 (DDWRT)
  - Windows 10 machine: 192.168.13.116 (I have tried both static and DHCP IP - no difference)
  - NAS connected to basement router: 192.168.13.150
  - Printer connected to basement router: 192.168.13.50
  - Computer connected to basement router: 192.168.13.100
  - ROKU connected to second floor router via Ethernet: 192.168.13.106
- Ping tests:

  - Windows 10 on second floor router ping basement router via WiFi: Fail
  - Windows 10 on second floor router ping basement computer/printer/NAS via WiFi: Fail
  - Windows 10 on second floor router ping google.com via WiFi: Success
  - Windows 10 on second floor router ping basement router via ethernet: Success
  - Windows 10 on second floor router ping basement computer/printer/NAS via ethernet: Success
  - Windows 10 on second floor router ping ROKU via WiFi: Success
  - Windows 10 on second floor router ping google.com via ethernet: Success
  - iPad on second floor router ping basement computer: Success
  - iPad on second floor router ping basement router: Success
  - Computer on basement router ping Windows 10 machine on second floor router via WiFi: Fail

In a nutshell, it looks like the Windows 10 machine specifically cannot see anything connected to the basement router, but it *can* see the internet. It can also see devices connected to the second floor router (e.g. ROKU).  Second floor items can also see basement items (iPad works okay via wifi; ROKU works via ethernet - both can access the NAS in the basement).

Output of `route -4 print`:

```
===========================================================================
Interface List
  5...54 e1 ad 71 de a7 ......Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (4) I219-V
 10...ae ed 5c b9 c0 67 ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
 17...ac ed 5c b9 c0 68 ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #2
 15...00 ff b0 04 2e e0 ......TAP-Windows Adapter V9
  8...ac ed 5c b9 c0 67 ......Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265
  9...ac ed 5c b9 c0 6b ......Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     192.168.13.1   192.168.13.116     50
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
     192.168.13.0    255.255.255.0         On-link    192.168.13.116    306
   192.168.13.116  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.13.116    306
   192.168.13.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.13.116    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link    192.168.13.116    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.13.116    306
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

Any suggestions on what may be happening? I'm confident the router setups are okay because everything seems to work fine with other platforms; the problem seems to be specific to the Windows 10 machine on WiFi.

Comment: It may be your firewall. Try disabling it and ping again.

Comment: Thanks; thought of that, no firewall enabled.  Even if it was: wouldn't the firewall have prevented ethernet pings from working?

Comment: Firewall on the router is meant more so for the the internet.In this intranet the local pc's anti-virus and firewall would prevent the pings from working. Disable firewall on the local pc.

Comment: Thanks.  No firewall enabled, period.  On router or PC.  No anti-virus installed either.

Comment: There may be a firmware update for your router?

Comment: Can you ping the ip address on the Wi-Fi interface of the second floor router? And the ip of the Ethernet interface? And the ip of the Ethernet of the basement router etc, etc? How do you know which router are you actually connected to? Is it possible that your non windows devices are connected to the basement even when they are on the second floor?

Comment: Thanks; added more info.  Hesitant to do a firmware update because it is a specific machine - I don't want to potentially break everything else by a bad firmware update.

Comment: What is the output of "route -4 print" on win10 when it's connected via wifi?

Comment: @bcs78 - added output.

Comment: Maybe you're using wireless isolation / guest network? (TBH this "question" does not really fit the Q/A concept of SE)

Comment: After you pinged something in the basement what is the output of "arp -a"? This must be something on the DD-WRT.

Comment: Plus: do you have the same problem if you change the ip address on the windows machine (like .216 instead of .116)?

Comment: 1) Have you confirmed the Win 10 box is using the same subnet mask as the rest of the network? 2) Can you ping another device on the upstairs Wi-Fi from the basement router if you give it the same IP the Win 10 box has? 3) How are the two routers connected [e.g. LAN port to LAN port, or something else (bad!)]? 4) What IP subnet is configured on each router's WAN interface? *Please post responses as an edit to your question, not only as comments.*

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because in 2018 the author indicated that "It looks like there is something materially wrong with both routers in my house; the issues above seem to resolve if I do a full power-down"

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your Windows 10 box's WNIC is losing its ability to receive multicasts (including broadcasts), which breaks ARP, which keeps it from being able to address packets to devices that aren't in its ARP cache.

As a simple test of this hypothesis, add a static ARP mapping, in the Windows 10 box, for one of the boxes it can't ping. If that allows it to ping that box, you know ARP was broken somehow.

Many WNICs are buggy when it comes to dealing with a separate cipher for multicasts/broadcasts than for unicasts, which is the case when original WPA (TKIP) is left enabled alongside WPA2 (AES-CCMP). So if you've left original WPA enabled on either of your routers, be sure to disable it so you're in pure WPA2-(AES-CCMP)-only mode.